# How to handle HTTP status codes?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, alamofire, http-status-codes

i am using Alamofire. Therefore in the response there're status codes. Should i check and handle every status code case available or what should i do to handle these.

```
switch response.response?.statusCode {
                case 201:
                    print("created user")
                case 400:
                    print("Bad request")

                // ...........
                default:
                    print(response.result.value)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no need to check for each and every status codes. What I would normally do is to check if the request is successful or fail by using the template below.

```swift
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in

    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        if let httpURLResponse = response.response {
            if httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                // Success
            } else {
                // Response Unsuccessful
            }
        } else {
            // Response Unsuccessful
        }
    case .failure:
        // Request Failed
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes but i want to know which error is thrown so i can show them to the user. I'm building my own api

Answer (score 0):

You can check for response code is between 200-299 inclusive. That will tell you request was successful. Any other code is, failure.

If you want to show specific errors then use response codes. This is list of standard [response codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). If you have control over API, stick to standard codes.

Comment: Yes but i want to know which error is thrown so i can show them to the user. I'm building my own api

Answer (score 0):

```
    httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
    print(httpResponse.statusCode) // this will shown the status code so you can easily get which type of error code is generate

    if(httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
    {
        //Success
    } 
    else
    {
        //Failure
    }
```

> You can check the types of error

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Yes but i want to know which error is thrown so i can show them to the user. I'm building my own api

Comment: This will help you https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: yes but for example if i take code 400 which is bad request and 401 which is unauthorized i want to track each case and show them to the user. For that i need to hceck every statuscode available or not?

Comment: You have to set using API for different status code

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

See the following point to get the status code from `HTTPURLResponse`, I hope it helps you.

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
     print("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
     if httpResponse.statusCode == 200{
         //Success
     }else{
         //Failed
     }
}else {
     //Failed
}
```

Comment: Yes but i want to know which error is thrown so i can show them to the user. I'm building my own api

Answer (score 0):

You don't normally need to actually know the specific error code, just whether the request was successful or not. But I could see for a developer tool or something similar you may want to show the actual code.

Something like this would be good, there's not really a need to check for the case of every possible status code.

```
if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
  print("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
  if httpResponse.statusCode == 200{
    //Success
  }else{
    //Failed
    statusCodeLabel.text = httpResponse.statusCode 
  }
}else {
  //Failed
}
```